# Is there a MSSQL `copy only` equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In MSSQL, so that a randomly requested full backup does not affect the differential and transaction log backup chains, we have the option to use the `copy only` mode.

Is there an equivalent of this mode in MySQL (phpmyadmin)? or is this concept irrelevant in MySQL/phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

The standard tools to make backups that is included with MySQL Server are [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) and the newer successor, [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlpump.html). These are both capable only of making backups in a "copy only" mode. They don't support incremental or differential backups.

You can use [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) to make incremental or differential backups.

Making a full backup does not interfere with the chain of incremental backups, it just takes more space to store an extra copy of the database.

MySQL Enterprise Backup might have this feature too, but I haven't used it. I use the open-source Percona XtraBackup.

Comment: Yah that's awesome - thanks Bill!